# Existence of a set of vectors with restriction on inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose I have $n$ unit-norm vectors $V= \{ v_{1},\dots, v_{n} \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$  where $k \ll n$. You can assume that $k=\frac{n}{C}$ for a constant $C$, or that $k=\frac{n}{f(n)}$ for some non-negative function $f(n) =o(n)$  if you are interested in concreteness.

Suppose further that for every $v_i \in V$ there exists $S_{i} \subset \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with $|S_{i}|= \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor $ such that

$$\langle v_{i},v_{j} \rangle <0 \ \ \ \  (\forall j \in S_{i})$$

My goal is to find a largest subset $U$ of $V$, such that
$$\langle u,u^{'} \rangle >0 \ \ \ \ \ (\forall u,u^{'} \in U) $$

I am interested in finding lower bounds on the size of such a set $U$. The case where $k=n-2$, it is easy to show that there exists a set $U$ with the desired properties having size at least 2. I am wondering if this can be generalized. i.e. if $k \approx \frac{n}{C}$ can we find a set $U$ of size $C+1$?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:
You may instead assume that

$$\langle v_{i},v_{j} \rangle < \theta _{1} \ \ \ \  (\forall j \in S_{i})$$
and 
$$\langle u,u^{'} \rangle >\theta_{2} \ \ \ \ \ (\forall u,u^{'} \in U) $$
for some chosen $-1 < \theta _{1}<0$ and $0< \theta _{2} < 1$

if this is easier to reason about.

Comment: The condition that $\forall v_i \in V, \langle v_{i},v_{j} \rangle <0$ for at least $n/2$ such $v_j$ seems VERY restrictive.  E.g. this is not even possible with $k=1, n=3$ because among the $3$ real numbers two of them must have the same sign.  How should we interpret that when $n$ is odd anyway?

Comment: @antkam Sorry about that, the restriction is actually that $(1-\epsilon)|S_{i}| \leq \frac{n}{2} \leq (1+\epsilon)|S_{i}|$ for $\epsilon $ approaching 0 as $n$ tends to infinity. The actual value of $k$ I'm interested in is $n/\log n$. It corresponds to embedding the vertices of a random graph on the unit sphere and then saying that the points corresponding to the neighbors of a given vertex lie strictly in the opposite hemisphere. It is possible to embed a random graph on $n$ vertices on $S^{k}$ with $k\approx \frac{n}{2\log n}$ having these properties